# Changing displayed image from several thumbnails on a sidebar with javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where I currently display a large plot (made with jqplot), and then a sidebar with a range of smaller plots.

What I'd like to be able to do is to change the large displayed plot based on whichever of the smaller plots the user clicked on (without having to reload the page).

I have been searching around online for a while with no luck, and hoped someone would be able to point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't really picture what you are trying to do, but you can redraw. if you have all the your data saved in an array you can simply redraw using the new values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have your new data simply initialize a new plot with the new data.

```
function onSomeEvent() {
    chart = $.jqplot('chart', newDataSeries, newOptionsObj);
}
```